# How to get access logs

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn, sanic

Currently I am running my sanic(microframework) webservice with gunicorn as a daemon and I would like to save all logs in files(access and error)

My config:

```
reload = True
daemon = True
bind = '0.0.0.0:6666'
worker_class = 'sanic.worker.GunicornWorker'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = 'access.log'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
errorlog = 'error.log'
```

Next I start the webservice:

```
gunicorn --config config.py app:app
```

So, my errorlog works, but I get absolutely no accesslogs.

There are no hints in the documentation about this issue, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 29):

could you try :

```
gunicorn --config config.py app:app --access-logfile '-'
```

And see if anything is logged on stdout(console output)?

Comment: No luck. When I'm tried to hit my endpoint , I dont see any log regarding the request

Comment: @srikarkulkarni, it is because you are overriding the cmd switch `--access-logfile` through gunicorn config. Try removing `accesslog` or change it to `accesslog = '-'`.  https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#logging

Answer (score 2):

If You are using `logging.config.fileConfig('someFile.conf')`, make sure that You use `disable_existing_loggers=False` argument, so it will be:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('someFile.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

Documentation 
here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig

Otherwise access logs are suppressed.

Leaving existing loggers alive might lead to appearing of other logs, for example, from `requests` or `urllib3` library. Do not worry, just disable at the next line, if You do not need them:

```
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 1):

use supervisord to start the gunicorn service with logging parameters.

```
[program:sanic]
directory=/home/ubuntu/api
command=/home/ubuntu/api/venv/bin/gunicorn api:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker -w 2
stderr_logfile = log/api_stderr.log
stdout_logfile = log/api_stdout.log
```

This works perfectly for me so I can just tail -f log/api_stderr.log

Comment: Forgot to mention, why don't you add nginx as a reverse proxy? Then nginx can handle the pure 'access logs' even before it reaches sanic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply from the sanic framework directly.

check the link

[How to change the default sanic log directory to a custom directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270646/how-to-change-the-default-sanic-log-directory-to-a-custom-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a log config to the Sanic App and set the a file instead of sys.stdout as stream for the access log handler.

```
app = Sanic('test', log_config=CUSTOM_LOGIN_CONFIG)
```

You can copy the default config from log.py in the sanic folder

```
accesslog_file = open('accesslog_file.log','w')


CUSTOM_LOGIN_CONFIG = dict(
    version=1,
    disable_existing_loggers=False,

    loggers={
        "root": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["console"]
        },
        "sanic.error": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["error_console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "qualname": "sanic.error"
        },

        "sanic.access": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["access_console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "qualname": "sanic.access"
        }
    },
    handlers={
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "generic",
            "stream": sys.stdout
        },
        "error_console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "generic",
            "stream": sys.stdout
        },
        "access_console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "access",
            "stream": accesslog_file
        },
    },
    formatters={
        "generic": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]",
            "class": "logging.Formatter"
        },
        "access": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - (%(name)s)[%(levelname)s][%(host)s]: " +
                      "%(request)s %(message)s %(status)d %(byte)d",
            "datefmt": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]",
            "class": "logging.Formatter"
        },
    }
)
```

This is gonna work even if you run the the app with gunicorn.